Why are split monomorphisms equalizers?
The nlab states about a split monomorphism $m: A \rightarrow B$ with a retraction $r$:

Any split monomorphism is a monomorphism, in fact a regular monomorphism (it is the equalizer of $∘$
and $1_B$)

While I see that a split mono is a mono, I am struggeling to see why it is an equalizer of  $∘$ and $1_B$.
It is easy to see that $m \circ r \circ m = m = 1_b \circ m$, but I do not see why for any other morphism $f: C \rightarrow B$ with $m\circ r\circ f = f$ there exists exactly one morphism $k_f$ such that $f=m\circ k_f$.

Just take $k_f = r \circ f$.

If $m\circ k_f=f=m\circ r\circ f$ then $k_f=r\circ f$ since $m$ is monic.
